# parameter not passed to angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to pass a parameter to an angular controller. It doesn't work. I get this error message:

> "Failed to load template: App/Views/CustomerDetail.html".

I'm using MVC and angular routing mechanism.

Here's my project struсture:

[image]

And, my route config file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Customer",
            url: "Customer/{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Customers" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "order",
            url: "order/{*catchall}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Orders" });

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My angular config with HTML5 models:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/Customer', {
        templateUrl: 'App/Views/Customers.html',
        controller: 'customerController'
    }).
    when('/Customer/:customerId', {
        templateUrl: 'App/Views/CustomerDetail.html',
        controller: 'customerDetailController'
    }).
    when('/order', {
        templateUrl: 'App/Views/Orders.html',
        controller: 'orderController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}]);
```

And, my Home controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Customers()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Orders()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I am trying URL http://localhost:1458/Customer/1

I think I'm making doing something wrong with the routing mechanism. Can you explain to me, please? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What URL are you trying?

Comment: I am trying this URL http://localhost:1458/Customer/1 It raising error

Comment: Did you actually tried to hook that html by direct link like `http://localhost:1458/App/Views/CustomerDetail.html` ? I recommend you to store front-end files in from-end folder (app in your case).